# fetching large number of data from oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Dears,

i have a table which stores about more than one million email addresses
what is the best way to fetch all data without facing performance or memory
issues

in my application i tried these methods :

-row number method 
- over analytic function

Comment: Post your query, table structure and index structure please.

Comment: Also what is the programming language context - is it SQL*Plus, PL/SQL, pre compiled language or JDBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the lazy loading method. you bring chunks of data from server and there will be more requests but less payload, I mean you can query for 100 items and on the callback of that query you can call query again 100 items starting for  and index you increment.

```
$startingPoint = 0;
$step = 100;
$query = "Select * from table limit $step offset $startingPoint";
$startingPoint+= $step;
```

Code is just to draw the steps and its not in a certain language, just for explanation only. Configure this to make your infinite scroll article theme or anything else. You can incorporate this into a function and call it until you have a callback err, meaning you get an error from database, meaning you have no more results. The ammount of data will be too big for the browser, so read bellow for my opinion.

If you have data that can be shown in a table, I would recommend dataTables , they have a great configuration for server side processing, you you get only data required instead of all and sort it on client side. My opinion is that Data tables is the best option for modular data, and you can search , sort, paginate with no stress.

Comment: their are no such thing like limit or  offset  in oracle

Comment: And my question now it is....Where you specified that? your question is incomplete but i tried to help you with and Idea, Do you even read what you ask? What is Stackoverflow? A bouch of wizzards trying to guess what you need and what it is your problem?

Comment: i mention it in the title  of the question above 
"fetching large number of data from oracle database"

Comment: very clear very specific and it doesn't need any wizard or any super power